# Create a general currency symbol mixin for any [small] text

Tags: css, sass, alignment, currency, scss-mixins

I have to show some prices in different places on a site I am building. For that, I created a `sass` mixin that should help to create the currency symbol I want before the price and with a smaller `font-size`. An example of what the prices should look like and how my mixin ended up are shown below.

My mixin:

```
@mixin add-currency($symbol: "R$") {
  margin-left: 17px;
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    bottom: 0px;
    content: $symbol;
    @include s.font(12);
    left: -17px;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

How my prices should look like:

[image]

As you can see, the currency symbol should be aligned with the baseline of the number, but in some cases the symbol ends up aligned with the bottom-most point of the comma, like this:

[image]

[image]

For the examples above, where the symbol isn't properly aligned, their `css` look like this:

First wrong example:

```
color: #1e273a;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 1.3333333333rem;
margin-left: 17px;
position: relative;
```

Second wrong example:

```
margin-left: 17px;
position: relative;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-size: 1.5625rem;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 2.0833333333rem;
```

I haven't found what, in the examples above, could be leading to this misalignment in the currency symbol, and also haven't found a way to correct this. The ideia behind my mixin is to make possible to just add this to any [small] text and add to it the chosen currency symbol, and although I know it won't work for every possible case, I believe for these two cases my mixin should work, right?

Thanks in advance for your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

The currency symbol in your mixin may be misaligned due to the difference in `line-height` between the symbol and the pricing text.

If we have the solution for that `line-height` fixing we will be having the solution then:

Might be that adjustment of line-height with `inherit` property will solve the issue.

```
@mixin add-currency($symbol: "R$") {
  margin-left: 17px;
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    bottom: 0;
    content: $symbol;
    @include s.font(12);
    left: -17px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: inherit; 
  }
}
```

Comment: The same `line-height` makes the currecny symbol align to the middle of the father element.